# Null pointer exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'c.a.a.a.a.a.c.d0 Database.W()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, android-room

My Android app has logged the exception shown below on a smartphone of a user (Huawei P20). com.mypackage.database.Database is a class where I defined the `DatabaseEntities` and `DatabaseDAOs` for my Room database (a shortened version is at the bottom). I don't know what `W()` is.

Does somebody see why this null pointer exception could be thrown? I also have a custom keyboard shipped with my app and in the custom keyboard I'm also writing to the database but that's the first time I got this exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'c.a.a.a.a.a.c.d0
> com.mypackage.database.Database.W()' on a null
> object reference
>
> --------- Stack trace ---------
>
> ```
> c.a.a.a.a.a.d.j.onTouch(Unknown Source:13)
> android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12624)
> android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12873)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5771)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5535)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4983)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5036)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5002)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5157)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5010)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5214)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4983)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5036)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5002)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5010)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4983)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7803)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7768)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7726)
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8007)
> android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:202)
> android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
> android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:386)
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
> ```

```
package com.mypackage.database;

import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@androidx.room.Database(entities =
        {DatabaseEntities.Session.class,
                DatabaseEntities.Accelerometer.class,
                DatabaseEntities.LinearAcceleration.class,
                DatabaseEntities.Gyroscope.class,
                DatabaseEntities.MagneticField.class,
                DatabaseEntities.Proximity.class,
                DatabaseEntities.Light.class,
                DatabaseEntities.StepCounter.class,
                DatabaseEntities.RotationVector.class,
                DatabaseEntities.AudioMode.class,
                DatabaseEntities.BackgroundService.class,
                DatabaseEntities.KeyboardTouch.class,
                DatabaseEntities.KeyboardKey.class,
                DatabaseEntities.KeyboardMetadata.class,
                DatabaseEntities.KeyboardPrivateMode.class,
                DatabaseEntities.KeyboardSession.class
        }, version = SettingValues.DB_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.AccelerometerDAO accelerometerDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.LinearAccelerationDAO linearAccelerationDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.GyroscopeDAO gyroscopeDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.MagneticFieldDAO magneticFieldDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.ProximityDAO proximityDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.LightDAO lightDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.StepCounterDAO stepCounterDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.RotationVectorDAO rotationVectorDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.AudioModeDAO audioModeDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.BackgroundServiceDAO backgroundServiceDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.KeyboardTouchDAO keyboardTouchDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.KeyboardKeyDAO keyboardKeyDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.KeyboardMetadataDAO keyboardMetadataDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.KeyboardPrivateModeDAO keyboardPrivateModeDAO();
    public abstract DatabaseDAOs.KeyboardSessionDAO keyboardSessionDAO();
}
```

**Edit**

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            resValue "string", "app_version", "Version: ${defaultConfig.versionName}"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            resValue "string", "app_version", "Version: ${defaultConfig.versionName}"
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        releaseDebugKey {
            initWith release
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        releaseDebugKey {
            // Use the debug signature
            initWith debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:1.0.0-beta9'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    // Glide library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8'
    implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.llollox:androidtoggleswitch:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Dao creates lot of internal classes. Please check the implementation class wrt it.

Comment: Proguard enabled ?

Comment: @NanPd Which implementation class do you mean?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes I have enabled proguard. Please see my edit with the build.gradle file in the post above. Is there some error or problems with it? Should I disable minifyEnabled and remove getDefaultProguardFile?

Comment: @machinery `Should I disable minifyEnabled and remove getDefaultProguardFile? ` for test case, you can do this?